# Outputting spaces in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following variable in my xslt template.

```
<xsl:variable name="spaces" select="'&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;'"/>
```

In the template, I am using the variable as such:

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="InvestmentNone = 'true'">
      <u>X</u>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
      <u xml:space="preserve">
         <xsl:value-of select="@spaces" xml:space="preserve"/>
      </u>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

So, basically, I would like spaces to show up with underline if there's when 'InvestmentNone' is 'false'.  The problem is that in the above code, the spaces do not show up.  However, if I remove the line

```
<xsl:value-of select="@spaces" xml:space="preserve"/>
```

and add

```
&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;
```

directly in place, the spaces show up with underline.  How can I get the variable method to work?  The reason for that is that later on I will use the variable to pad spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access the variable, you have to prefix its name with `$` instead of `@`:

```
<xsl:variable name="spaces" select="'&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;'"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$spaces"/>
```

The prefix `@` addresses attributes, and since there's probably no attribute called *spaces* in the context node, you get an empty string when accessing `@spaces`.

Comment: Thank you.  You are absolutely correct.  I did replace the @spaces with $spaces and now it works.

Comment: I also added the padding code as such: concat('x', substring($spaces, 1, string-length($spaces) - string-length('X'))) ...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Martin's correct answer, I would point out that using xml:space="preserve" in a stylesheet is usually a bad idea. It means that the whitespace text nodes before and after your xsl:value-of instruction become significant, as if they were enclosed in xsl:text. I don't know why this didn't put any underlined whitespace into your HTML, though it would probably only show up as a single space once the browser has rendered it.